# При индексации сайта Wordpress страницы /front-page.php и /index.html показывают 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Главная страница изначально создавалась в каталоге front-page.php , но при индексации сайта данная страница отображалась как not found. После этого я удалил страницу и перезалил все в index.php, но все равно при индексации страницы front-page.php и index.html отображаются как not found:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт с ошибкой - `http://savhouse.com.ua`

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно с 404. Этих файлов нет и не должно быть в корне сайта.

index.html  вообще нет в ВП и не нужен, а front-page.php -  не каталог, файл ([шаблон](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B)) который создаётся в корне темы. Он отвечает за главную страницу сайта, которая находится по адресу: httр://site.com/

Comment: Да, я знаю, но суть в том что поисковая система индексирует именно эти страницы. А это очень плохо для SEO

Comment: 404 вообще не может индексироваться. В принципе. Могут быть только переходы на них. Но это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вот именно. Ищите, где у вас на сайте прописаны переходы на эти "страницы".